# Filling in gaps between pavers with a caulk-like material?

Tags: driveway, pavers

I was walking home the other day and came across a group of workers installing pavers for a driveway.  The thing that caught my attention was one guy who was filling in the gaps (about 3/8 to 1/2 inch) between the pavers with a caulk gun loaded with a tube that contained some kind of tan material.

I've used sanded caulk before, but only indoors.  I'm assuming that this is something similar, but designed for a slightly harsher environment.

What was this material, and what are the advantages and disadvantages to using this to fill the gaps between pavers?

Comment: Could it have been concrete? go poke at your neighbors driveway and see if the material is hard (like concrete) or softer (like sand).

Comment: Well, it was flowing out of the tube as if it was pliable, like caulk. Do they put concrete (or concrete like material) in tubes like that?

Comment: Not that you would buy at the store (I don't think), but the guys doing the job might have a rigged up system they invented to save time.  It would probably make it easier (less cleanup) to put concrete between each paver using a caulk gun, than to try and get it in any other way.  Although I could be completely wrong about it being concrete, so...

Comment: I wouldn't think it's concrete. If they filled in ALL the gaps with something rigid like concrete, that will prevent natural expansion/contraction, and this "grout" will crack and fall out, or the pavers themselves could crack if the stuff is as strong or stronger than the pavers' base marterial.

Comment: I can't think of a single advantage over polymeric sand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could very well be an outdoor sanded caulk, meant to seal the gaps in the pavers to prevent weeds and water, which can disturb a nice level surface of pavers over time. I mean, if you'd trust a 1/2" bead of general-purpose silicone caulk to seal flashing on your roof, I would trust it to perform similarly in most any other application.

It could also be a grout-like substance, used in much the same way as for tile. This kind of material would be more rigid, and I wouldn't count on it lasting very long if you get cold winters; it'll crack, loosen and eventually crumble away as the pavers, and the ground itself, shrinks and expands.

Answer (score 0):

It is a calk like substance, applied with a caulking tube that has sand mixed in it.  I removed a 2X2 base for a lamp lamp from my driveway.  As an accent, I installed a compass rose made to order with slate and stone that is flush with the pavers.  Rather than use paver sand I used this. It has been there for 10 years and is now showing signs of shrinking.  What I might try this time is use a colored caulk and impregnate the top with paver sand.

Answer (score -1):

Sikens self leveling caulk available in tan or gray is my guess

Comment: This is just a comment as-is. It doesn't describe anything, or why you think this would be what they saw.